# How to find that a column in one table is also used in another table

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have table structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TEMP_TXT_DATA](
[ReaderID] [smallint] NOT NULL,
[Pin_Code] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[P_Date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[P_Time] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[TACode] [smallint] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I want to change this table but I don't know what is TACode. How can I will know that this field is used in other tables in the database?

Comment: Are you trying to find out if the field is used, or just if another table in the database also has the name `TACode`? The latter is answerable, the former is a very broad question.

Comment: you could check for any foreign key relationships, or you can hope that it's named the same and look at sys.objects or  [sys.columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106(v=sql.90).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use the system schema views.  Assuming the field is identically named in other tables in your database:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'TACode'
```

You can also use `sys.columns` system catalog, but you'll have to join that to `sys.tables` to get the actual table name.